# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php

Ok, I'm trying to clean my code from injections, etc,etc. and I'm getting this fatal error:

**Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in....**

Here's the line where it throws the error:

```
$val=mysql_real_escape_string($val)=$_SESSION['val']=strip_tags($_POST['val']);
```

Why is it throwing this error?

UPDATE: ok, thanks for the answers, I moved `mysql_real_escape_string($val)` to another part in the code, this fixed the error.

Comment: Which variable are you trying to make safe, `$_SESSION['val']` or `$_POST['val']` ?

Comment: I want both safe $val is sent to DB and $_SESSION['val'] remains on page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assigning a value (return of `strip_tags` that is stored in `$_SESSION['val']`) to a **function** !
I guess you want this:

```
$val=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['val']);
```

and about using `strip_tags` on a http parameter look at this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Another thing to note:

Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I've been told about PDO and MySQLi several times on the forum now, and I will change my code later on, this code is just for an introduction course to PHP

Comment: @grasshopper you should start right now by using PDO / mysqli. no excuses. read the introduction of my pdo mysql tutorial (draft): https://gist.github.com/2362466

Answer (score 2):

You can only assign values to variables.